# JQuery selectors -- why does adding a filter return MORE elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know there are a lot of questions about JQuery selectors, but I'm not seeing my particular problem.

If I use this selector, it finds 2 elements, both class "dluSingle".  One has an id of "F45_rdefault_F48” and one has an id of “F45_r0_F48”.

```
linkGridDiv.find('.dluSingle')
```

So, I figured that this code would return just the element with the id of "F45_r0_F48."

```
linkGridDiv.find('.dluSingle [id *= "r0"]')
```

Instead, it returns 5 elements, all containing "r0" in the id, but none of them of class type "dluSingle".

It would make more sense to me if it found nothing.  Why would adding an extra filter return more results instead of fewer?  What am I not understanding?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that, there's no space between the class selection and the attribute selection.

```
linkGridDiv.find('.dluSingle[id *= "r0"]')
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was the answer...such a dumb little thing, but this was really driving me crazy...thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

By including a space between your class and your "filter", jQuery treats your filter as a descendant selector.

In other words, it looks for any child, grand-child, etc. element that is *below* your dluSingle class. To look for the element with the class "dluSingle" and "r0" in the id you can simply do:

`linkGridDiv.find('.dluSingle[id *= "r0"]')`

For completeness,

`linkGridDiv.find('.dluSingle [id *= "r0"]')`

looks for any element with "r0" in the id that is a *descendent* of an element with the class ".dluSingle", and

`linkGridDiv.find('.dluSingle > [id *= "r0"]')`

looks for any element with "r0" in the id that is a *child* of an element with the class ".dluSingle".

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense!  I couldn't see why the space made any difference, but now I see why.  Many thanks for the explanation!